# jQuery is not defined, even thought it clearly is

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, electron

Here is the error message from the browser console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at code.js:6:1

I just have a simple function utilizing jQuery, which I have put into the document.ready block, to ensure jQuery will load first.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    function showView(viewName){
        $('.view').hide();
        $('#' + viewName).show();
    }
    console.log('test');
});
```

Here, console promts that 'jQuery is not defined' , even thought it is.

I have seen a similar issue question, but I have checked if:

1. Other plugins may overwrite the $ tag, they don't.
2. jQuery is loaded in the Head tag of the page BEFORE my own script.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/code.js"></script>
</head>
```

I have also noticed that this was once working. Only as I have been adding more stuff to the code.js script, stuff has gone wrong.
Firstly, the $ tag went "undefined" thus I have placed all of these into the document.ready block.
Secondly, the $ tag in the document.ready block went "undefined".
And lastly, the jQuery class before document.ready went "undefined" as a whole, and now refuses to work.

Here is a Minimal Reproducible Example, hosted on glitch.

https://harmonious-dot-clam.glitch.me/

I dont know if this is helpful, but this is a part of an electron project.

I have no idea what went wrong here, as it initially worked fine. As I said, I checked all the answers that helped others, but none worked. Please try and help, as this is delaying my project and I need help with this.

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Comment: And also perhaps post the HTML from the top down to the `<body>` since we probably don't have enough to go on here yet. There might be something else in your code.js file that is causing issues...hard to tell.

Comment: if the website is on the Internet, can you post a link to it?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] using a StackSnippet that replicates the problem?

Comment: You can also try to move `<script src="js/code.js"></script>` to just before the body close tag `</body>` and FYI `jQuery(document).ready(function () {` is recommended to be `jQuery(function () {`  ref: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Your comment "Only as I have been adding more stuff to the code.js script, stuff has gone wrong." really to me points to some issue there; perhaps run it through https://jshint.com/ to see what it says about your code

Comment: Your example gives me the error:  - Mixed Content: The page at 'https://harmonious-dot-clam.glitch.me/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: I have added the Minimal Reproducible Example. Also checked jshint and it doesn't say anything important (just some unused variables, not conflicting with jQuery).

Comment: I have now used some other jQuery import tag on the website: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> which seems to solve this issue, however in my original electron project on my computer, even with the changed script tag, the issue persists.  It seems like nothing has changed there.

Comment: So the initial issue is solved. But now change the inline onclick to .on("click" INSIDE the ready function

Comment: AND add quotes to the ID you are passing: `$(function () {
    function showView(viewName){
        $('.view').hide();
        $('#' + viewName).show();
    }
   $("button").on("click", function() {showView("page2")});
});`